# What are the error of the following class

Tags: c++, oop

what are the error, i just type from coursera, there are error in the init function (the constructor)
there are compile error,  i am a very beginner in c++.

int w_.,int h_. what are the meaning of this,

how should i declare the constructor correctly.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class cRectangle{
    public:
    int w,h;
    void init (int w_.,int h_.){
        w=w_.;
        h=h_.;
    }
    int Area(){
        return w*h;
    }
    int Perimeter(){
        return 2*(w+h);
    }
};
int main(){
    int w,h;
    cRectangle r;
    cin>>w>>h;
    r.init(w,h);
    cout<<r.Area()<<endl<<r.Perimeter();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error? Could you post it?

Comment: Yes the `.`s in the `init()` function are invalid. May be change your learning resources for something better? Also, that's not a valid constructor function.

Comment: Can you show the page from coursera where they have such code?

Comment: how would you declare a valid constructor

Comment: A valid constructor would be `cRectangle(int w_, int h_) : w(w_), h(h_) {}`

Answer (score 1):

Using a dot (.) as part of an identifier in C++ variable names/function parameters is not valid syntax.  This should work as intended

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class cRectangle{
    public:
    int w,h;
    void init (int w_,int h_){
        w=w_;
        h=h_;
    }
    int Area(){
        return w*h;
    }
    int Perimeter(){
        return 2*(w+h);
    }
};
int main(){
    int w,h;
    cRectangle r;
    cin>>w>>h;
    r.init(w,h);
    cout<<r.Area()<<endl<<r.Perimeter();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're at it, show also what a valid _constructor definition_ would look like, and how to use it.